# how to show an element that is being toggled and hide the others

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div(.test-two) within a div(.text-one) which is hidden. Using a click, the div(.test-two) gets revealed, but I also want all revealed divs(.test-two) to hide by sliding in.

I could just set them to display: none, but this doesn't give me the slide in effect and ends up just making them disappearing.

```
$('.test-one').on("click", function () {
    //$('.test-two').css('display', 'none');
    $(this).find('.test-two').slideToggle();
});
```

See link - http://jsfiddle.net/1eddy87/hy23ctdn/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added one line to your javascript:

```
$('.test-one').on("click", function () {
    //$('.test-two').css('display', 'none');
    $('.test-two').slideUp();
    $(this).find('.test-two').slideToggle();
});
```

I think this is what you're wanting.
http://jsfiddle.net/emdgwn38/

It closes all of the test-two class first, then toggles open the one that was clicked on, but does it seamlessly, so the closing of the clicked on div gets interrupted immediately.

Additional Information:(edit)

Here's how to make the already opened div stay open on further clicks:

```
$('.test-one').on("click", function () {
    //$('.test-two').css('display', 'none');
    $('.test-two').slideUp();
    if ($(this).find('.test-two').is(":visible")){
    $(this).find('.test-two').stop();}
    else{
    $(this).find('.test-two').stop().slideToggle();}
});
```

It checks to see if the div is visible, and if so, makes it stop the previous line calling for all the divs of that class to close, but only on the div that is being clicked. http://jsfiddle.net/emdgwn38/2/

Comment: you're a champion mate

Comment: As a further note: If you add a stop() to this line  $(this).find('.test-two').stop().slideToggle(); you can close the last remaining div as well, instead of it always opening back up. If you want to get really fancy, you can check if the clicked on div is already open, and do nothing.

Comment: How would I check if the clicked div is already open, and do nothing? @Gary Hayes

Comment: Updated answer for you.